# JAXB - trying to marshall a java object from external jar

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to marshall this class using jaxb

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

public class TaskPost {
...
Point point;
...
}
```

(with getters and setters)

Class point is imported from an external jar which i have no source code to, how can i manually marshal this?
I need to use specific methods to get the data from the point class (for now its printing one of the fields   SRID>0/SRID> (which are html tags))

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://javapapers.com/jee/jaxb-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JAXB implementation does not require any annotations on a model class so it would apply the default mappings to it.  Alternatively, you could write an `XmlAdapter` to convert `Point` to/from your own model class for the purpose of marshalling/unmarshalling.

Comment: Thank you very much, adding your link that helped me a lot:
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html